# Electron - No desktop notifications

Tags: notifications, electron

I've been following Gary Simon's [tutorial](https://coursetro.com/courses/22/Creating-Desktop-Apps-with-Electron-Tutorial/lessons/7) on how to make a basic app on electron, but I can't seem to get the desktop notifications working on my computer. I'm 100% sure the code is correct because I performed `npm start` both on my root folder and *his* root folder (which I downloaded from his website, performed `npm install` and then `npm start` to run his code), but I'm getting no desktop notifications. Is there a setting on my computer that's preventing it from working?

Here is a picture of what it should look like:

[image: bitcoin toaster popup]

I checked all my notification settings on my Windows 10 machine, but everything is turned *on* as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue

Comment: You can give a try to electron-tray notifications: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md. It works for me.